# From local script, terminate (then recreate) all EC2 instances in Auto Scaling Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, autoscaling, aws-cli

**The setup:**

I have an AWS Load Balancer with an Auto Scaling Group attached to it. It launches instances of an AMI that I have configured to act as a base setup for our application server.

I used the `User Data` setting to do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/server
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i /home/ec2-user/app-server.key' git pull
composer install
```

That is to say: when the Auto Scaling Group spins up a new instance, it pulls the latest code from GitHub, updates the composer dependencies (it's a Lumen-based PHP RESTful application service), and is ready to go.

This all works.

When I manually `detatch` all of the EC2 instances from my Auto Scaling Group, new instances are immediately created and successfully grab the latest code. Lovely!

**What I'm trying to do**

After I commit my server code to GitHub, I want to run a local command - say, `deploy staging`, which automatically does the following:

1. Terminates current instances in the Auto Scaling Group
2. This causes new instances to be created, which then update to the latest code.

**What I'm doing now**

It's still very manual. I commit to GitHub, and then I have to go to the AWS web console and 'detatch' all my EC2 instances so that new ones will take their place - and then I have to go terminate those detatched instances.

**The question**

So - given what I'm trying to accomplish, how can I get this done?

From my Windows PC I want to type in a single word which will do all of the above.

Perhaps my ordering of things is incorrect - for example, new instances should be spun up *before* terminating the old ones, etc - and in this case, please advise me as to the best way to accomplish things.

I'm also looking for *exact* recommendations re: how to implement this. Do I need to download that AWS CLI tool for Windows? How do I execute AWS commands from my home PC? Etc..

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Alternatively (perhaps this is a cleaner way?), I could also just tell the current instances in my Auto Scaling Group/Load Balancer to 'do a GitHub update'.. but I have no idea how to do this. The instances only do this once upon first being created.

Answer (score 2):

This whole setup is sort of brittle. You could take a look at CodeDeploy: https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/

For your specific setup, if you're not allowed to touch it/alter it too much, what I would do is:
In the running instances I would periodically pull from github and compare with what is running. If there is a new version I would stop the service. The instance would become unhealthy and get recycled and get the new version.
You probably want to setup up a somewhat random schedule between different machines to ensure they don't all get recycled at the same time.

Comment: We're allowed to touch anything we want (it's completely our architecture, codebase, etc.)

With that in mind, would you advise anything different from the above?

The 'periodic pull from github' has the downside of me not being able to trigger a deployment *immediately* the second I commit my code.

Comment: what does immediately mean to you? is it 1 second, 1 minute, 5 minutes? what does it matter? (ie you should still allow for a certain period of time where the 2 versions run side by side) you also don't want to kill all the instances in the process of deployment. If it's acceptable to kill all the instances you can always setup a github webhook + sns + lambda to do this on the spot when the push happens (sample: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/dynamic-github-actions-with-aws-lambda/). Your lambda function can terminate the instances.

Comment: I say 'immediate' because in some of our environments - like our staging one which is really used for development purposes amongst developers, and turnaround time is important - I'd really like to just run a `deploy staging` command on my PC and have everything begin the process. However, I agree with you that 'killing all instances' is unacceptable. In a perfect world, we'd spin up new instances, wait until responsive, then substitute existing scaling group instances with them...

Comment: Might there be another way to 'tell' the EC2 instances to 'go update from GitHub'? I mean, this could be another approach that doesn't involve replacing currently running EC2 instances..

Comment: you can definitely notify the instance (combination of git webhooks + sns + lamda and/or sqs but think it's overkill). the easiest thing to do is to write a cron that runs each minute on the machine and polls the state in github.

Comment: Hmm. Cron every minute that does a `git pull` and then perhaps a `composer install` (it's a PHP-based framework based on Composer for dependency management). That's not a bad idea. Would this be a bit dangerous for production, though? (Might not want all commits to be pulled into production at same time as staging, etc!) Is this why you called the setup 'brittle'?

Comment: you can always get creative. check in a file that tells the machines what to pull (the commit id you want to use). have different files for development and production. make sure that the script that the cron runs can only have one instance running at a time (and abort if instance already running) to prevent situation in which you do more than 1 "install" at a time.

Comment: the setup is 'brittle' because it's hard to observe and control. you don't really know if the install succeed and if it did what are the versions are running on the machines at a point in time. composer might fail to pull in the dependencies. you may have multiple machines running multiple versions. it works but there are multiple point where it can go south. you normally want a controlled environment where you know at any point in time what is going on.